# AcquireTokenAsync result is null

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When attempting to acquire auth token and header for azure ad app to pull graph api reports, the auth token result returns null. I don't get an error message. Been working on this for over a week. Anyone have any idea?

```
function Get-AuthToken {
    $TenantName = "foo.com"
    $ClientID = "blah-123-blah-123-blah"
    $RedirectURI = "urn:spoderman"

    Import-Module MSOnline

    $ModuleBase = (Get-Module MSOnline | Sort-Object Version -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).ModuleBase
    $Adal = "{0}\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll" -f $ModuleBase
    $AdalForms = "$AdalForms = "{0}\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll" -f $Modulebase"

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($Adal) | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($AdalForms) | Out-Null

    $Authority = "https://login.windows.net/$TenantName"
    $ClientCred = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential" -ArgumentList $ClientID, $ClientCred
    $AuthContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $Authority, $false

    $AuthResult = $AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync($ResourceAppIdURI, $ClientCred).result

    return $AuthResult
}

$Token = Get-AuthToken
```

Token returns null.

I've gotten this to work using `ActiveDirectory.UserCredential` and `$authContext.AcquireToken($ResourceAppIdURI, ClientID, $RedirectUri, "Always")` where the user is prompted for creds, but I want this to run as an automated task. Hopefully I'm at leas ton the right track...

Comment: Alright, guys. It took a couple of weeks, but I was finally able to answer my own question. Please check out [this github](https://github.com/jdanl89/Get-Office365Reports/commit/6d1a880a0175ea3c7eff8247be366fa65bf95f9f)